# Why am I getting a '.class' expected error? Simple Array script

Tags: java, arrays

My program is creating an array and allowing the user to input 10 double precision numbers. Then the program will sort them in order from lowest to highest. I have the following but receive .class expected error upon compiling. Any ideas on why this is happening? Note * I have not been able to compile this yet so I don't even know if this will work. *

```
import java.io.*;

public class ArrayDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        double[] intValue = new double[10];
        String[] numbers = {"first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh", "eighth", "ninth", "tenth"};
        int len = intValue.length[];

        BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            System.out.println("Enter the " + numbers[i] + " number");
        intValue[i] = Double.valueOf(dataIn.readLine());

        {

        for (j = 0; j < (len - 1) -i; j++)
            if (intValue[j] > intValue[j+1]) 
            {
                temp = intValue[j];
                intValue[j] = intValue[j+1];
                intValue[j+1] = temp;
            }

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++);
        {
            System.out.println("Array after sorting in ascending order");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(intValue[i]);

        }

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any input. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int temp = 0;` should be `double temp = 0;`

and

`int len = intValue.length[];` should be `int len = intValue.length;`

and

`for (i = 0; i < 10; i++);` should be `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)`

[Sample](http://ideone.com/6WePS)

---

EDIT

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        double temp = 0;
        double[] intValue = new double[10];
        String[] numbers = {"first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh", "eighth", "ninth", "tenth"};
        int len = intValue.length;

        BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            System.out.println("Enter the " + numbers[i] + " number");
            intValue[i] = Double.valueOf(dataIn.readLine());
        }


        for (j = 0; j < len; j++)
        {
            for(k = 0; k < len; k++) {
                if (intValue[j] > intValue[k]) 
                {
                    temp = intValue[j];
                    intValue[j] = intValue[k];
                    intValue[k] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Array after sorting in ascending order");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(intValue[i] + ", ");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Now it spits out "Enter the first number" "Enter the second number" and so on without prompting the user to enter the numbers it has something to do in the

     System.out.println("Enter the " + numbers[i] + " number");
    intValue[i] = Double.valueOf(dataIn.readLine()); area i believe

Comment: The dataIn.readLine() call is made outside of your for loop. You need to have it inside brackets along with the preceding println() call.

Comment: So i moved the line inside the loop, now it prompts me for the first number like it should and then it proceeds to ask for the first number again and errors out with a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error.

Comment: You need to remove the semicolon after the last 'for' statement in your program. The way you have it currently written, the body of that for statement is empty. This will cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when the intValue array is indexed with a value of 10.

Comment: You had a couple issues, one your sort was wrong so I fixed that. Two you for loops were all messed up with weird brackets and a semicolon at the end of the last loop.

Comment: OH! I see now. The example helped me understand how this is supposed to work, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

```
int len = intValue.length[];
```

You don't need [] after length and you also tried to assign int temp to a value in a double array

```
temp = intValue[j];
```

Also using an IDE like Eclipse/NetBeans/IntelliJ would definitely help!

Answer (score 0):

```
int len = intValue.length[];
```

should instead be:

```
int len = intValue.length;
```

---

Also, some of your bracketing appears to be incorrect. I believe, for example, that you want the following snippet:

```
for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)  
    System.out.println("Enter the " + numbers[i] + " number");
intValue[i] = Double.valueOf(dataIn.readLine());
```

Changed to:

```
for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
   System.out.println("Enter the " + numbers[i] + " number");
   intValue[i] = Double.valueOf(dataIn.readLine());
}
```

---

You have a number of other logical errors in your code as well. Let me know, after you work with the code for a while based on the current answers, if you have any specific questions and I will help you further.