# '.class' expected error

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, loops

Hi I am working on a bumper cars game and I am getting the error

```
P:\162>javac bumpercardemo.java
```

bumpercardemo.java:13: error: '.class' expected
                printGrid(bcar[], NUMCARS);
                                ^
bumpercardemo.java:34: error:  expected
        public static void printGrid(bcar[], int NUMCARS)
                                           ^
2 errors

I am new programmer and have never seen this type of error.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class bumpercardemo
{
public static void main (String args[])
{
    final int NUMCARS = 16;
    bumpercar bcar[] = new bumpercar[NUMCARS];
    createcars(NUMCARS, bcar);
    printGrid(bcar[], NUMCARS);
}

public static void createcars(int NUMCARS, bumpercar bcar[])
{
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    Random generator = new Random();
    char symbol = 'A';

    for (int i=0; i<NUMCARS; i++)
    {
        bcar[i] = new bumpercar(x, y, symbol);
        symbol++;

        x = generator.nextInt(bcar[0].getCarSymbol());
        y = generator.nextInt(bcar[0].getCarSymbol());
    }
}


public static void printGrid(bumpercar bcar[], int NUMCARS)
{
    //nested loop
    for(int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
    {
    System.out.printf("\n");
        for(int k = 0; k<16; k++)
        {
            for(int l = 0; l<NUMCARS; l++)
            {
            if((bcar[l].getX() == k) && bcar[l].getY() == j)
            System.out.printf("%s", bcar[l].getCarSymbol());
            else
            System.out.printf("- ");
            }
        }
    }
}


}
```

I think it has to do with the [] but since I am passing in an array I am not sure what else to do.

I checked out [Why am I getting a '.class' expected error? Simple Array script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535073/why-am-i-getting-a-class-expected-error-simple-array-script) but I can't full understand how it pertains to my program.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the `[]`. Since you're passing the array off, you just pass the variable name.

```
printGrid(bcar, NUMCARS);
```

You did it correctly when calling  `createcars()`, so just emulate that style.

Comment: if you don't mind helping me once more. My printgrid prints 16 16X16 grids.  There is a problem with my triple nested loop, but I dont get why. The first two should just print the grid, then the third should search through the bcar array to see if the coordinates match. However it doesn't. See anything? @A--C